# Are cyclic codes bounded by a continuous function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, coding-theory

In coding theory, we  know that if you take the function

\begin{equation}
  \alpha_q(\delta) := \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \max \{ R(C) \mid \delta(C) \ge \delta \mid C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q^n\}.
\end{equation}

then the function is continuous. Here $R(C)$ is the rate of a code $C$ and $\delta(C)$ the relative minimum distance. This follows by spoiling a code appropriately to have codes in the vicinity of any point in the graph. A proof is in Tsfasman and Vladut's "Algebraic-geometric codes" book, for example.

I think the original proof is by Manin, but I am not sure (would like to know!)

Now if I restrict only to cyclic codes and define a similar function as the following:

\begin{equation}
  \alpha_q^{\text{cyclic}}(\delta) := \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \max \{ R(C) \mid \delta(C) \ge \delta \mid C \text{ is cyclic} \}.
  \label{eq:defi_of_Alp_cyc}
\end{equation}

Is it known that this function is also continuous? The usual proof for the general case cannot be extended (as far as I could tell).

EDIT: This question is an open problem, because it proves an open problem.

However, I am now changing my demand. Instead of 'cyclic', I can choose other class of codes like 'Goppa' codes or 'transitive' codes and make similar constructions $\alpha_q^{\text{Goppa}}$ or $\alpha_q^{\text{trans}}$ for instance. Are any such functions known to be continuous?

Comment: On a second thought, I think proving it to be continuous will solve the long-standing "good cyclic codes" conjecture.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question on the origin of $\alpha_q$. The original proof goes back to Manin's article ["What is the maximum number of points on a curve over $\mathbb F_2$"](http://jairo.nii.ac.jp/0021/00004357/en),  J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo, 1981. Manin and Marcolli have some more recent articles ([[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5135), [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0653)) studying $\alpha_q$ from a sort of a statistical mechanical perspective.

Comment: I have changed my question now so I cannot accept this answer, but thank you for telling me about this paper (and also providing the full text)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the sockpuppeting.

If we prove $ \alpha_q^{\text{cyclic}}$ to be continuous, we solve the long-standing problem of "are there good cyclic codes?".

This is because  $ \alpha_q^{\text{cyclic}}(0) = 1$ trivially and by continuity we would then have $ \alpha_q^{\text{cyclic}}(\delta)> 0 $ for some $0 < \delta < 1$. This proves good cyclic codes.

As far as if the original proof is by Manin, I would still like to know!